# awk multiple lines from a command and print horizontally in a row

Tags: awk

I run a command that displays the following  result

```
Model = FordMustang  
Drivetype = Rear Wheel Drive  
Horsepower = 300 hp @ 6500 rpm (3.7L V6)   
Transmission = 6-Speed SelectShift® Automatic with Paddle Shifters, optional   
Wheel1type = Alloy   
Wheel2type = Magwheel   
Wheel3type = Steel   
Warranty1 = Bumper to Bumper: 3 years / 36,000 miles   
Warranty2 = Safety Restraint System: 5 years / 60,000 miles   
Price1 = Dealer 52000   
Price2 = ExShowroon 54000
```

I want to format the output and print data into rows

```
**Model     DriveType         Horsepower       Wheel       Price**
```

Can i use awk to do this..?

Comment: yes you can :-) Please post what you have tried and we'd be glad to further assist you!

Comment: Heres a hint at one way `awk '{x=x?x"\t"$1:$1}END{print x}' file`

Comment: Hey Fredrick,  
I tried this
COMMAND |  awk -F '[=]' '{print $2}'

but in the above command that I executed, it only gives me whatever is after the "=" sign.

What I was after is IF I run a command that gives me the output, I can pick and choose what I can print that too in transpose format.
this will be helpful for me to use in a script that will generate the data for me.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
awk -F'=' '{printf "%s", $1}' test.txt
```

Comment: In what way does this "format the output and print data into rows"?

Comment: Output says header and hence it will just print header, so i believe it will give the output as asked i.e. just header.

Comment: Hey almas,
thanks for the post. what I was after is if I run a CMD that gives me above output, i can awk specific values from diff lines without having to go back to run the command again and then awk again and the print it in a format that is transposed. 
I want to derive this so I can put it in a sctipt that can get me the transposed output fir multiple execution.